# how to get and read path filename 4 file on one click c#

Tags: c#, windows

i have filename A6010509_DCODE.txt, A6020509_DCODE.txt, A6030509_DCODE.txt, A6040509_DCODE.txt

i want to get allfile and read allfile on one click button

Answer (score 1):

Check with using [FileInfo.Name Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.name(v=vs.80).aspx)

As Example Code

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
foreach(string file in files)
{
  Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(file));
}
```